The wire:on event is triggered and rolled back
The event occurs, the text changes, but immediately returns to the previous state (I went through the debugger, it will change for a moment). Where to look and what I don't understand. I use livewire 3.
Component code
public function change($clientId)
    {
        $this->dispatch('changeText', $clientId);
    }

Component template
<h1 id="target-text">Old Text</h1>

<button wire:click="change({{ $client->id }})">Press</button>

@script
<script>
    $wire.$on('changeText', () => {
      const oldText = document.getElementById('target-text');
      oldText.innerText = 'New Text';
    });
</script>
@endscript

I expect it, but not...
<h1 id="target-text">New Text</h1>


Have a look at the documentation, it appears there could be syntax issues. e.g. $wire.$on(...) the docs show $wire.on(...)

I've tried it both ways - it's useless.
I read that when installing Breeze and Livewire in the same project the AlpineJS library may conflict, it is present in both packages. I need to try to reproduce the error on a clean project without Breeze. All the signs that this JS somehow affects the DOM are obvious (Captain Obvious:)). I will unsubscribe based on the result. Thanks!
